# Tab index is not working from select to next button in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<td >Club City</td>
 <td > <input style="width: 98%" id="SnapI_txtCity" title="* Club City" class="boxStyle" onclick="" onchange="" maxlength="50"> </td>  
<td>Sprinkler system present in club</td>
 <td > <select id="SnapII_ddlSprinklerSys" title="* Please select Sprinkler system present in club " onclick="" onchange="">
                                    <option selected="" value="SEL">Select</option>
                                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                                    <option value="No">No</option>
                                </select>
<tr>                         
  <td style="text-align: right">
                    <img id="imgNext" onclick="ShowDiv('N')" name="imgNext" src="../_gfx/next.gif" runat="server"></td>
   </tr>
```

Upto select button tab index is working,after select it is circulating from first.How i will solve it in asp.net?without adding tabindex     it works upto last textbox.but it doesot goes to next image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input,select,img").each(function (i) { $(this).attr('tabindex', i + 1); });
    });
```